# How to access the internal Track object in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm using the find_zero function from the Roots package. From the documentation:

*verbose - if true a trace of the algorithm will be shown on successful completion. See the internal Tracks object to save this trace.*

Here's my code:

```
root=find_zero((f,f_derivative), initial_guess, Roots.Newton(), verbose=true)
```

The output is this:

```
Results of univariate zero finding:

* Converged to: 1.0
* Algorithm: Roots.Newton()
* iterations: 3
* stopped as |f(x_n)| ≤ max(δ, |x|⋅ϵ) using δ = atol, ϵ = rtol

Trace:
x_0 =  0.8000000000000000,   fx_0 =  0.5877852522924732
x_1 =  1.0312656693970701,   fx_1 = -0.0980661300327017
x_2 =  0.9998990605287050,   fx_2 =  0.0003171106961631
x_3 =  1.0000000000033835,   fx_3 = -0.0000000000106296
x_4 =  1.0000000000000000,   fx_4 =  0.0000000000000001

* function evaluations ≈ 8
```

I'm trying to find a way to access x_0, x_1, x_2... and fx_0, fx_1, fx_2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is not very clear on this, but you first have to create a `Tracks` object:

```
 t = Roots.Tracks(Float64, Float64);
```

Here the first `Float64` is the type of your `x_0`, `x_1`, etc., the second `Float64` is the type of your `fx_0`, `fx_1`, etc.

Then pass this to your `find_zero` call:

```
 root=find_zero((f,f_derivative), initial_guess, Roots.Newton(), verbose=true, tracks=t)
```

After this, the trace is saved in the `t` object, and you can access the x values and fx values as:

```
 display(t.xs)
 display(t.fs)
```